# Can't connect to SQL server from Android studio

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

Here is my connection class, i have comments where it fails, and where the exception is caught.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionClass {
String ip = "cis-linux2.temple.edu";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "*********";
String un = "******";
String password = "*******";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(classs); //throw exception here
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {//exception thrown
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

I added the lib jtds-1.2.7.jar, which is what I was told was needed here http://www.parallelcodes.com/connect-android-to-ms-sql-database-2/

by going to new module, and import .jar, and I can see it at the same level as my app and Gradle Scripts folders on the Android Studio sidebar, but it still won't work.  Is there another way to import a library that I should have used, or is it with the code its self?

Comment: I fixed the library, but now it's stalling on line: conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);  and not throwing any exceptions

Comment: Can you try adding the port number to the url? The only other difference in my working application is I leave the user/password out of the connection string and call the overload DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password)